# SQL To check if a set of dates fall within a specified range of dates

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which holds dates when a room is unavailable in the schema:

```
ROOM_ID | DATE_UNAVAILABLE
```

I need a sql query that checks if a room is available during between a range of two dates - some thing along the line of

```
Select All rooms that are constantly available between date 1 and date 2
```

or rather

select all rooms that don not have a date entered in the date unavailable table which falls between date 1 and date 2

I'm using php MySQL here.

Answer (score 2):

The inner query finds the room that are not available, then we use a Not-exists left join to remove those dates from our results, leaving us with available rooms only.

```
SELECT r.ROOM_ID
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ROOM_ID
    FROM tableName
    WHERE DATE_UNAVAILABLE BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'
    GROUP BY ROOM_ID
  ) g ON r.ROOM_ID = g.ROOM_ID
WHERE g.ROOM_ID IS NULL
```

Alternativly, if you have correct indexes in place, skipping the group may be faster:

```
SELECT r.ROOM_ID
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN tableName g ON r.ROOM_ID = g.ROOM_ID
    AND g.DATE_UNAVAILABLE BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'
WHERE g.ROOM_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have another table, say `rooms` it can be something like this:

```
select * from rooms r where not exists
(select * from room_unavail u
    where r.id = u.id and u.date_unavailable between date1 and date2)
```

You can not do this just with the one table you specified, since when the table is empty -- all rooms are available but you won't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Let myRoomId be the ID of given room, and dateStart and dateEnd be the beginning and ending dates of time interval. Than:

```
select count(*) from tblRooms
where date_unavailable>=dateStart and date_unavailable<=dateEnd
and room_id = myRoomId
```

given select returns 0 if room is available.